# DCG capable of reading a propositional logic expression

Tags: prolog

As I said in the title, I am trying to do an exercise where I need to write a DCG capable of reading propositional logic, which are represented by lowercase letters, operators (`not`, `and` , and `or`), with the tokens separated by whitespace. So the expression:

```
a or not b and c
```

is parsed as

```
a or ( not b and c )
```

producing a parse tree that looks like:

```
or(
  a,
  and(
    not(b),
    c
  )
)
```

To be completely honest I have been having a hard time understanding how to effectively use DCGs, but this is what I've got so far:

```
bexpr([T]) --> [T].
bexpr(not,R1) --> oper(not), bexpr(R1).
bexpr(R1,or,R2) --> bexpr(R1),oper(or), bexpr(R2).
bexpr(R1, and ,R2) --> bexpr(R1),oper(and), bexpr(R2).
oper(X) --> X.
```

I would appreciate any suggestions, either on the exercise itself, or on how to better understand DCGs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The key to understanding DCGs is that they are syntactic sugar over writing a recursive descent parser. You need to think about *operator precedence* (how tightly do your operators bind?). Here, the operator precedence, from tightest to loosest is

- not
- and
- or

so `a or not b and c` is evaluated as `a or ( (not b) and c ) )`.

And we can say this (I've included parenthetical expressions as well, because they're pretty trivial to do):

```
% the infix OR operator is the lowest priority, so we start with that.
expr --> infix_OR.

% and an infix OR expression is either the next highest priority operator (AND),
% or... it's an actual OR expression.
infix_OR --> infix_AND(T).
infix_OR --> infix_AND(X), [or], infix_OR(Y).

% and an infix AND expression is either next highest priority operator (NOT)
% or... it's an actual AND expression.
infix_AND --> unary_NOT(T).
infix_AND --> unary_NOT(X), [and], infix_AND(Y).

% and the unary NOT expression is either a primary expression
% or... an actual unary NOT expression
unary_NOT  --> primary(T).
unary_NOT  --> [not], primary(X).

% and a primary expression is either an identifer
% or... it's a parenthetical expression.
%
% NOTE that the body of the parenthetical expression starts parsing at the root level.
primary --> identifier(ID).
primary --> ['(', expr(T), ')' ].

identifier --> [X], {id(X)}. % the stuff in '{...}' is evaluated as normal prolog code.

id(a).
id(b).
id(c).
id(d).
id(e).
id(f).
id(g).
id(h).
id(i).
id(j).
id(k).
id(l).
id(m).
id(n).
id(o).
id(p).
id(q).
id(r).
id(s).
id(t).
id(u).
id(v).
id(w).
id(x).
id(y).
id(z).
```

But note that all this does is to **recognize** sentences of the grammar (pro tip: if you write your grammar correctly, it should also be able to generate all possible valid sentences of the grammar). Note that this might take a while to do, depending on your grammar.

So, to actually *DO* something with the parse, you need to add a little extra. We do this by adding extra arguments to the DCG, viz:

```
expr(       T        ) --> infix_OR(T).

infix_OR(   T        ) --> infix_AND(T).
infix_OR(   or(X,Y)  ) --> infix_AND(X), [or], infix_OR(Y).

infix_AND(  T        ) --> unary_NOT(T).
infix_AND(  and(X,Y) ) --> unary_NOT(X), [and], infix_AND(Y).

unary_NOT(  T        ) --> primary(T).
unary_NOT(  not(X)   ) --> [not], primary(X).

primary(    ID       ) --> identifier(ID).
primary(    T        ) --> ['(', expr(T), ')' ].

identifier( ID       ) --> [X], { id(X), ID = X }.

id(a).
id(b).
id(c).
id(d).
id(e).
id(f).
id(g).
id(h).
id(i).
id(j).
id(k).
id(l).
id(m).
id(n).
id(o).
id(p).
id(q).
id(r).
id(s).
id(t).
id(u).
id(v).
id(w).
id(x).
id(y).
id(z).
```

And that is where the parse tree is constructed. One might note that one could just as easily *evaluate* the expression instead of building the parse tree... and then you're on you way to writing an interpreted language.

You can fiddle with it at this fiddle: https://swish.swi-prolog.org/p/gyFsAeAz.pl

where you'll notice that executing the goal `phrase(expr(T),[a, or, not, b, and, c]).` yields the desired parse `T = or(a, and(not(b), c))`.